# No result is displayed in IBM Cloud

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud

```
SELECT COUNT(CRIME_ID) FROM CRIME_DATA;
SELECT * FROM CRIME_DATA;
```

For the first one, there is no error, but I don't get any results.
For the second one, I see the table content properly.
It looks like for any query with `SELECT *`  I get results, but not for any other queries.

Comment: Please don't write all upper case, that's like screaming/yelling.

Comment: provide the table schema and note that CRIME_ID is different from "CRIME_ID" and "Crime_ID" - SQL identifiers...

Comment: The first query will always return one row with one column -- even if the column value is `0` (well, it could return an error).  Perhaps you are not looking in the right place.